# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '7:00' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant figure how to convert this time. I seen other ways on how to convert other values but not time. Can anyone help thanks.

```
select count(*) 
from reporting_call_matrix AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
Where CALENDAR_DATE Between '10/1/2015'  and '10/31/2016'  and  Call_hour Between '7:00' and '19:00'
```

Comment: well, I mean....what's the datatype of `Call_Hour`?, seems like it's an `INT`

Comment: can you give some sample data please?

Comment: I added SQL Server as the database tag because of `WITH (NOLOCK)`.

Comment: You might also read this article about NOLOCK. It brings a lot of things to the table that most people don't know about. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, `call_hour` would appear to be an integer.  So, try this:

```
select count(*) 
from reporting_call_matrix AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
Where CALENDAR_DATE Between '2015-10-01' and '2016-10-31' and
      Call_hour Between 7 and 19;
```

I strongly advise you to use ISO standard date formats for date constants.